# GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency under CLR 4.0

Tags: .net, clr

In the 4.0.3 uppdate of the CLR there was a new enum value added to the GCLatencyMode enumeration. What will happen if I use this enum value and the code is run by an end user on CLR 4.0 without the 4.0.3 update? How can I write code that reliably detects and uses a fallback under the 4.0 CLR?

Edit: the code must be built for 4.0 but may be run on a higher CLR, for example 4.5 where I hope I can use new features? Obviously in this case the enum value can't be compiled by name, but perhaps using its integer value?

Comment: Your program will bomb.  This mode is only documented for .NET 4.5, whether it does anything at all for 4.0.3 and is stable is impossible to find out.  Just change your framework target to 4.5, simple and trouble-free.

Comment: Building for 4.5 is not an option at the moment because of OS support, but it would be neat when our 4.0 program is run *on* a CLR that supports it (be it 4.5 if necessary rather than 4.0.3), if we could use the SustainedLowLatency mode there, without having to make separate builds for 4.0 and 4.5.